# Does having unique and lot of small partition in a table effect performance or create extra load in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I have a table with 4 million unique partition keys
select count(*) from "KS".table;

### count

4355748
(1 rows)

I have read the cardinality of Partition Key should not too high and also not too low, which
means don’t make partition key too unique. Is it correct?
The table does not have any clustering key. Will changing data partitioning help with the load?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the use case... If you don't have natural clustering by partition, then maybe little sense to introduce it. Also, what are the read patterns? Do you need to read multiple rows in one go, or not?

Number of partitions has an effect on the size of the bloom filter, key cache, etc., so as you increase the number of partitions, bloom filter is increased, and key cache has less hits (until you increase its size).

Comment: Do you think Cassandra will had a bottleneck when accessing partition index . As we know, process that happen on disk will be much
slower than on memory.So if we have too many Partition Key, Cassandra will iterate the partition
index and it will make high server load?  For each read request
(select statement) to this table, Cassandra need to iterate 50 million times to find the index?

Comment: there are optimizations for finding partition keys faster in the index

Comment: Are they configurable or inbuilt?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Cassandra is using consistent hashing for mapping partition key to physical partition, so cardinality should not matter.